# Different display of items in view/template depending on model in Django

Tags: python, django, templates

I have a model, that looks something like this:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Vote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_set')
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, related_name='topic_set')
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("user", "topic")
```

In my index view, I want to display a list of all the topics. If the user has already voted on the topic, it should show his score. If the user has not voted, it should display a form for the user to vote.

I have extended the model with this method as part of the `Topic` class:

```
def user_has_already_voted(self, user):
    if not Vote.objects.filter(topic=self.id,user=user.id):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

However I don't know whether this is the way to go in Django, since I don't know how to write a view with a corresponding template to perform this task. As of now, I am using a generic `IndexView`, which looks like this:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'topics/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_topic_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Topic.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

Answer (score 2):

use context. In view add:

```
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = {
            'is_voted' : self.user_has_already_voted(self.request.user),
        }
        context.update(kwargs)
        return super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**context)
```

and in template use:

```
{% if is_voted %}
     Show vote results
{% else %}
     Show vote form
{% endif %}
```

Comment: That looks like a cool way of doing something like this. Is it possible to change the context for each object in the queryset, or is the context the same over the whole view?

Answer (score 1):

You can access your user_has_already_voted in template:

```
{% if topic.user_has_already_voted %}
Show vote results
{% else %}
Show vote form
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I am not sure about this. The method expects a user as parameter, but as far as I know one cannot pass parameters to functions in templates. (Or at least not that easy)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `RedirectView` to achieve this:

in your views.py, do something like this (this is code I'm using in a current project, the idea ist quite similar.

```
class AbstimmungRedirectView(generic.RedirectView):

    def get_redirect_url(self, pk):
        abstimmung = get_object_or_404(Abstimmung, pk=pk)     
        if abstimmung.abgeschlossen(): 
            #Die Abstimmung wurde durch Angabe eines Enddatms als "Beendet" markiert
            return reverse('my_app:MultipleChoiceFrageResults', args=(int(pk),))
        else:
            return reverse('my_app:MultipleChoiceFrageDetail', args=(int(pk),))
```

you should replace my `abstimmung.abgeschlossen()` by your `has_voted()` and use the reverse url for the templates you want to show.